# Выборка чистого текста из Html

Tags: asp.net, c#, jquery

Допустим пользователь в Html редакторе набрал некоторый текст (с картинками, придуманными и понимаемыми браузером тегами и т.п.).

У меня есть этот Html. Как ГРАМОТНО убрать все эти теги и получить только текст? Т.е. убрать это форматирование и всё лишнее (картинки тоже) кроме текста.

Что можно использовать для реализации написано в тегах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Смотрите пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/mXL7u/3/)

```
$('#content').text();
```

Comment: <div id="content"><div>AJDJKSH</div>123</div>

У Вас вернёт: <div>AJDJKSH</div>123 
А мне надо получить: AJDJKSH123

Comment: А вы хоть проверили? [Смотрите ваш пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/QNbMy/)

Comment: Извиняюсь, не посмотрел :)

Перепутал с .html();

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery:**

```
var text = '<a href="someurl">Hello world</a>some text<img src="someimage">';
alert($(text).text());
```

Comment: см. первый комментарий на ответ @Deonis

Answer (score 0):

Ну на jQuery это можно сделать так:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
alert($("#n1").text()); // вывод: "12111"
});
</script>

<div id="n1">
<p>1</p><p>2</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ))) Угу... Сейчас и вам скажут, что это не работает =) И я, и FLK, а теперь и вы  - об одном и том же поём.

Comment: В смысле не работает?

Comment: okay) глупость автора вопроса =)

Comment: Можно забыть. ТС просто не на то обратил внимание.